# Get value of contact form 7 radio button

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

favorite
I have following radio buttons in contact form 7 and a few text fields and hidden fields.

```
[radio radio id:radio label_first "3" "6" "9" "12"]
```

Following are a few example lines of code in functions.php. I am able to get all the other values e.g text fields and hidden fields but not radio buttons.

```
function wpcf7_cstm_function($contact_form) {
    $title = $contact_form->title;
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

    if ($submission) {
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
    }
$txt = $posted_data['txt'];
        $text2 = $posted_data['txt2'];
$radio=$posted_data['radio']; 
}
```

Is there a way to get the value of selected radio button?

Comment: so is `$radio` null? are you sure 'radio' is the name of the radio button?

Comment: radio is not the name it is just for an example. All the values are being fetched but not of the radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

okay so i was able to get the value of the radio button through javascript on the page and assigning it's value to a hidden field in the form.